# Cell Value String Variable in Path Errors to "Bad File Name or Number"

Tags: excel, vba, string, path

Sorry for the long one, and it's probably something simple that I'm overlooking after so much time.

I'm writing a small program that in just a few clicks, pulls data from an actor's "deal memo" pdf and put's that info into one of four possible excel templates (in different sheets) to export as a new "contract" pdf.

The application identifies certain key words/values from other cells that determines which sheet/template is used.

The issue comes at the following step:
-Based on the keywords, I need the exported document to identify if a series of folders are created, and if not, create them, and step in to create more relevant folders before finally saving the file.

The structure example is as follows, relevant created folders in **Bold**:

C:\Work Folder\ **Deal Memo to Contract\Exported Contracts\Episode Number\Actor Name\Contract Type\final.pdf**

Each folder name is created based on variables pulled from cell values. It works just fine when I put the string variables in quotes for testing, and even when the variables are stated by themselves, it pastes the proper path in the admin cells as shown in the following picture - Range A14:A21

Screenshot of Dashboard Page, admin column to be hidden

[image]

But even though it looks like a proper path address in the cells, VBA throws a

> Runtime error 52:Bad file name or number on line 56, "PlayerExFolder = Dir(PlayerExPath, vbDirectory)"

Like I said, it's probably something simple. Any help would be great as I'm still pretty new to this.  Oh, and I'm working on the Daily_Direct section of the if statements, the others will be identical once this starts working. Thanks!

UPDATE - It turns out that I had narrowed it down to what I thought were extra spaces that were ruining the path/folder creation. They were invisible "Ghost" characters. Ended up using the Clean function on the cells that were being used to name the folders. Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
Sub export_pdf()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim MainExPath As String
Dim MainExFolder As String
MainExPath = Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("C3").Value & "\Exported Contracts"
MainExFolder = Dir(MainExPath, vbDirectory)
    
    If MainExFolder = vbNullString Then
        Answer = MsgBox("An export folder for the generated contracts does not exist, I will create one for you", vbOKCancel, "Create Contract Export Folder?")
        Select Case Answer
            Case vbOK
                VBA.FileSystem.MkDir (MainExPath)
            Case Else
        End Select
    End If

    Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A15").Value = MainExPath

Dim EpiExPath As String
Dim EpiExFolder As String
Dim currEp As Integer
currEp = Worksheets("Data").Range("F14").Value
EpiExPath = Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A15").Value & "\" & currEp
    Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A17").Value = EpiExPath
    
Dim PlayerExPath As String
Dim PlayerExFolder As String
Dim CurrPlayer As String
CurrPlayer = Worksheets("Data").Range("F8").Value
PlayerExPath = Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A17").Value & "\" & CurrPlayer
    Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A19").Value = PlayerExPath
     
Dim TypeExPath As String
Dim TypeExFolder As String
Dim CurrType  As String
CurrType = Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A7").Value
TypeExPath = Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A19").Value & "\" & CurrType
    Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A21").Value = TypeExPath
    
    
    If Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A7").Value = "Weekly_Direct" Then
    
        ElseIf Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A7").Value = "Weekly_Loan" Then
        
        ElseIf Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A7").Value = "Daily_Direct" Then
            
            EpiExFolder = Dir(EpiExPath, vbDirectory)
                    If EpiExFolder = vbNullString Then
                        VBA.FileSystem.MkDir (EpiExPath)
                    Else
                    End If
            
            PlayerExFolder = Dir(PlayerExPath, vbDirectory)
                    If PlayerExFolder = vbNullString Then
                        VBA.FileSystem.MkDir (PlayerExPath)
                    Else
                    End If
                
            TypeExFolder = Dir(TypeExPath, vbDirectory)
                    If TypeExFolder = vbNullString Then
                        VBA.FileSystem.MkDir (TypeExPath)
                    Else
                    End If
            
            'dateExFolder = Dir(dateExPath, vbDirectory)
                    'If typeExFolder = vbNullString Then
                     '   VBA.FileSystem.MkDir (currType)
                    'Else
                    'End If
                     
        ElseIf Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A7").Value = "Daily_Loan" Then
    
    
    End If
  
Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A15").WrapText = False
Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A17").WrapText = False
Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A19").WrapText = False
Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A21").WrapText = False
Worksheets("Deal2Contract").Range("A23").WrapText = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Does `C:\Work Folder\ Deal Memo to Contract\Exported Contracts\Episode Number\Actor Name\Contract Type\final.pdf` open a file when entered into the Run box or Windows Explorer? Should there be a space in front of Deal?

Comment: No, the file "final.pdf" was just an example, it doesn't create anything past Episode Number folder if I'm using the variable names. and the space in the example path was just to bold only the relevant sections.

Comment: I think I've narrowed it down to a floating " " space at the end of the name path making it not able to create the folder, etc... I'm playing around with the TRIM & REPLACE functions right now on that section and I've gotten it to generate the entire folder and naming structure, but it returns the name "Actor's Name" as "False" instead of the name. I hope this is really the issue cause I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why String wasn't working. I also restructured the Dim's to a more conventional place, but it didn't seem to have an effect.